making a complex curve cut on simple cylinder
I'm trying to make this Cylinder object with the curve cut that slides from it, I have already made the two in the back, it was done by making:
Cut-loops -- cutting faces -- Bevel the front edge. This method doesn't work in the cylinder because of the multiple faces that surrounds the form, can anyone aid me and give a hint of how can i make this in the cylinder?






Maybe begin with a 16 vertex cylinder, move down one vertex with Proportional Editing option on:

Remove the bottom faces:

Fill all these faces:

Create this edge loop:

Move it backwards:

Bevel it:

Move the vertices and change the topology a bit:

